# Firebase Swift FEventType.ChildChanged not working

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a structure as below,

```
  "Messages" : {
"0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe54" : {
  "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe5451879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce" : {
    "counter" : 3,
    "description" : "Breta",
    "lastMessage" : "B85",
    "lastUser" : "51879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce",
    "messageType" : "txt",
    "sortTimestamp" : -1.459861586060744E9,
    "updatedAction" : 1.45986158606074E9,
    "userId" : "51879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce"
  },
  "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe547bfe8604-58ad-4d18-a528-601b76dd2206" : {
    "counter" : 1,
    "description" : "Romeo",
    "lastMessage" : "",
    "lastUser" : "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe54",
    "messageType" : "txt",
    "sortTimestamp" : -1.459527387138615E9,
    "updatedAction" : 1.459527387138613E9,
    "userId" : "7bfe8604-58ad-4d18-a528-601b76dd2206"
  }
}
```

I have:

```
var messageRef: Firebase

messageRef = Firebase(url: "\(URL_BASE)").childByAppendingPath("Messages2").childByAppendingPath(userID)
```

The .ChildAdded code works well, even for just changes, but i would like to be notified as well ONLY when there is a change (for a sound notification, for example). With the .ChildChanged code, changes are not detected, what am I doing wrong?

According to the docs: "The ChildChanged event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node."

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

```
messageRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)
})  //working



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

messageRef.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
       print(snapshot)

  })  //not working
}
```

Comment: it looks like `ChildChanged` is inside `viewWillAppear`, but where is the `ChildAdded` code located?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, actually meant that if I use .ChildAdded, it works just fine, but not if I change that code to . ChildChanged. Both would be in viewWillAppear.

Comment: so it prints something only with `ChildAdded`? The docs use an example like `snapshot.value.objectForKey("key")`, maybe for some reason that makes a difference with `ChildChanged` instead of just printing `snapshot`

Comment: childByAppendingPath("Messages2") - take out the 2, as it should just be "messages" according to your structure.

Comment: @Jay I thought about that but why would it work with `ChildAdded`? Figured maybe he has Messages2 somewhere and didn't show it

Comment: Can you create an actual repro demonstrating that one works and the other does not? How are you verifying that data is actually changed *after* adding the change listener?

Comment: sorry I changed it to messages here just for clarity. I think I located the problem as well; I used a tabbarController and within some of the tabViews I do in viewDidDisappear removeObservers. I add them in the next view, but somehow it doesn't register. When i then move to a totally different viewController (say settings) and go back to the original one, it does work again.

Comment: so it has to do with the fact that adding and removing observers in a tabBarViewController work in mysterious ways, hmm. thank you so much for the answers. was stuck for a whole day here. I guess I'll just experiment further with regards to this.

Comment: I would like to know if the use of a tabbarcontroller (with in my case 4 tabbarViewControllers) is seen as one viewController by Firebase and where I have to remove observers. I guess I would need to make a new question however right?